# object 'patchworkGrob' is not exported by 'namespace:patchwork' on R 4.2.0

Tags: r

trying to install the packages clusterProfiler and enrichplot. In both cases, unable to load the packages because I get the error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'clusterProfiler':
 object 'patchworkGrob' is not exported by 'namespace:patchwork'
```

I have the current version of patchwork 2.4. I have tried uninstalling patchwork and installing an earlier version using devtools but still get the error.

Answer (score 2):

This has popped up on a couple with a couple of other threads as well.  There are two different patchwork packages in R.  One by Thomas Lin Pedersen (current version: 1.1.1 & described as "The goal of patchwork is to make it ridiculously simple to combine separate ggplots into the same graphic.") that is available through CRAN.  The second is from Anders Isaksson and colleagues (current version: 2.4 & described as "a bioinformatic tool for analyzing and visualizing allele-specific copy numbers and loss-of-heterozygosity in cancer genomes") and is available from Rforge.

Here's the problem, you probably want the first, and likely installed it.  If you, however, enable Rforge as a repository in Rstudio, it will then update the 2.4 version because it has a higher version number.  This will then preclude an number of other packages from updating.  It's unfortunate that both packages share the same namespace even though they are are unrelated packages.

To solve this, uninstall patchwork.  Make sure that Rforge is not selected as a repository (`setRepository()`) , and the reinstall it and make sure the version number is not 2.4 (should be 1.1.1).